# Fortran error: Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference

Tags: cygwin, fortran

I'm try to run an ocean temperature model for 25 years using the explicit method (parabolic differential equation).

If I run for a year `a = 3600` or five years `a = 18000` it works fine.

However, when I run it for 25 years `a = 90000` it crashes.

`a` is the amount of time steps used. And a year is considered to be 360 days. The time step is 4320 seconds, `delta_t = 4320.`.

Here is my code:

```
program task
!declare the variables
implicit none
! initial conditions
real,parameter :: initial_temp = 4.
! vertical resolution (delta_z) [m], vertical diffusion coefficient (av) [m^2/s], time step delta_t [s]
real,parameter :: delta_z = 2., av = 2.0E-04, delta_t = 4320.
! gamma
real,parameter :: y = (av * delta_t) / (delta_z**2)
! horizontal resolution (time) total points
integer,parameter :: a = 18000
!declaring vertical resolution
integer,parameter :: k = 101
! declaring pi
real, parameter :: pi = 4.0*atan(1.0)
! t = time [s], temp_a = temperature at upper boundary [°C]
real,dimension(0:a) :: t 
real,dimension(0:a) :: temp_a
real,dimension(0:a,0:k) :: temp
integer :: i
integer :: n
integer :: j


t(0) = 0
do i = 1,a
    t(i) = t(i-1) + delta_t
end do

! temperature of upper boundary
temp_a = 12. + 6. * sin((2. * t * pi) / 31104000.)

temp(:,0) = temp_a(:)
temp(0,1:k) = 4.

! Vertical resolution 
do j = 1,a
    do n = 1,k
    temp(j,n) = temp(j-1,n) + (y * (temp(j-1,n+1) - (2. * temp(j-1,n)) + temp(j-1,n-1)))
    end do
    temp(:,101) = temp(:,100)
end do


print *, temp(:,:)
end program task
```

The variable `a` is on line 11 (`integer,parameter :: a = 18000`)

As said, `a = 18000` works, `a = 90000` doesn't.

At `90000` get I get:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:

RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 15s)
```

I'm using a fortran on windows 8.1, NetBeans and Cygwin (which has gfortran built in).

I'm not sure if this problem is caused through bad compiler or anything else.

Does anybody have any ideas to this? It would help me a lot!

Regards

Comment: You should compile your code with run-time array bounds checking.  When you do you should find your error.  Which is related not to `a` but `k`.

Comment: Use `-fcheck=all -Wall -g -fbacktrace` when testing your programs with gfortran.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following lines from your code:

```
integer,parameter :: k = 101
real,dimension(0:a,0:k) :: temp
integer :: n

    do n = 1,k
    temp(j,n) = temp(j-1,n) + (y * (temp(j-1,n+1) - (2. * temp(j-1,n)) + temp(j-1,n-1)))
    end do
```

Your array `temp` has bounds of `0:101`, you loop `n` from `1` to `101` where in iteration `n=101` you access `temp(j-1,102)`, which is out of bounds.

This means you are writing to whatever memory lies beyond `temp` and while this makes your program always incorrect, it is only causing a crash sometimes which depends on various other things.  Increasing `a` triggers this because column major ordering of your array means `k` changes contiguously and is strided by `a`, and as `a` increases your out of bounds access of the second dimension is further in memory beyond `temp` changing what is getting overwritten by your invalid access.

After your loop you set `temp(:,101) = temp(:,100)` meaning there is no need to calculate `temp(:,101)` in the above loop, so you can change its loop bounds from

```
do n = 1,k
```

to

```
do n = 1, k-1
```

which will fix the out of bounds access on `temp`.

Comment: Thanks a tonne, that definitely fixed the crashing!

However the numbers seem to be wrong.
I forgot to point out that `temp(:,101) = temp(:,100)` was a boundary condition at the bottom. dT/dz=0 at ocean floor.

Comment: @Huntemerson well now that your code runs you can debug its logic and verify your algorithm is correct.  Sorry I can't help you there.